# Should I create one common trigger or several small triggers?

Tags: database, oracle, triggers

What is a better programming practise:

Writing one common trigger that handles several aspects/rules?

**Or**

Writing one trigger for each rule?

For example I have a database 'Library' with 4 tables:

Journal, Clients, Books, and Books_types.

Rules on INSERT into table Journal:

1. field DATE_END should be automaticly generated;
2. field COUNT in Books should be decreased;
3. field COUNT in Book_types should be decreased.

What is a better choice: 3 small triggers or 1 common?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends somewhat on the exact requirements (as always) but there are some pros for having just one trigger:

1. as per [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/triggers.htm#i13362) the execution order of triggers is undefined and I would not like to have any kind of indeterministic behavior in my application.

> Oracle fires multiple triggers in an unspecified, random order, if
>   more than one trigger of the same type exists for a given statement;
>   that is, triggers of the same type for the same statement are not
>   guaranteed to fire in any specific order.

2. According to the rule *"keep one information in one place"* I'd rather add all the logic in one trigger as well. You could have more than one procedure or function call in that trigger, in order to follow the *"divide and conquer"* pattern.
3. Most likely one trigger is faster in terms of execution time and doesn't increase the complexity as much as three triggers. Just imagine if you would have 300 triggers versus 100 triggers ...

Depending on whether you run into an `ORA-04091: table Journal is mutating` error you might even have to split your logic into several triggers. Check this site about [avoiding mutation tables](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551198119097816936).

Comment: Oracle fires multple triggers *of the same type* in an unspecified order, but there are four types: BEFORE statement, BEFORE row, AFTER row, AFTER statement.  Those types are executed in that order, but each type is order independent.  See "The Execution Model for Triggers and Integrity Constraint Checking" on the [same link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/triggers.htm#i13362).

Comment: I fully agree (therefore I wrote: _"It depends somewhat on the exact requirements ...."_): there is a certain priority given, e.g. a `BEFORE` trigger runs before the `AFTER` trigger. However, generally spoken, I would not split my logic into several triggers just because they are related to different columns. That was somewhere between my lines ... ;)

Comment: Yep, I was just clarifying.  It came across as ambiguous the first time I read it.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a best practice here; it depends entirely on what you're doing and how complex it is.

I would put the default value for field(s) in the `Library` table in a BEFORE row trigger.  So the default value of the `DATE_END` (assuming I couldn't use `DEFAULT SYSDATE` or `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as a field constraint).  That way I'm writing to the table once.  If I had `NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL` constraints on the field, I think a BEFORE trigger is the only way to do this.

Then I'd use an AFTER statement or AFTER row trigger for fields in other tables, primarily because there may be foreign keys or other similar requirements that require the data I'm currently inserting to actually be in the table (like an ID generated by a sequence).  It seems more philosophically correct, but I'm less familiar with Oracle convention than others.

Answer (score 0):

personally, i would do it with one trigger, makes it easier for the person maintaining it to see what's going on

Answer (score 0):

I think it will give **Mutating Error**. Because small triggers may contain some action that will generate Mutating Error.

For example-
You can not write update trigger for AFTER INSERT event.

Comment: On the other hand, having more than one trigger on a table might be a solution to get rid of mutating errors. See this article: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551198119097816936.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to implement rules to method with what you're going to generate inserts. Because rules of modify can grow up in futcher and this will affect dml performance

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using several, targeted triggers - one for each operation.

That way, you don't need to spend any time and write any code in the trigger itself to figure out what operation you're facing - it's obvious from the fact the trigger is `FOR UPDATE` or `FOR DELETE`. That makes the trigger code simpler, less error-prone, and easier to maintain in the future.